# What's the part of speech for "having difficulty"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Consider this sentence:

> I am having difficulty with the test.

Would "having difficulty" be considered an adjective in this sentence?
I imagine so as it describes the state of the person...

Comment: Although I can't find it labelled as such, I'd say 'have difficulty with' is cohesive enough to be classed as a [transitive, verbo-nominal] multi-word verb. There is a reasonably precise antonym that is a simplex verb ('master'). It's certainly a fixed expression (though 'have' declines normally), and is different from say 'We had a difficulty with the orientation of the sprockets'.

Comment: No: it's not an adjective. "Having difficulty" is not here a constituent. The verb phrase "am having difficulty with the test" is in the present progressive aspect, where the auxiliary verb "am" is head and the clause "having difficulty with the test" is its complement. "Difficulty with the test" is a noun phrase serving as object of "having". The meaning is roughly the same as "I am experiencing a problem with the test".

Answer (score 2):

> *I am having difficulty with the test.*

No: "having difficulty" is not an adjective, nor is it here a constituent. The matrix (main) verb phrase "am having difficulty with the test" is in the present progressive aspect, where the auxiliary verb "am" is predicator and the clause "having difficulty with the test" is its complement.

"Difficulty with the test" is a noun phrase serving as object of "having". The meaning is roughly the same as "I am experiencing a problem with the test".

Answer (score 0):

It is pleasant to meet you, *Having Difficulty*, I am TaliesinMerlin.

Puns aside, reading "having difficulty" as an adjective or a noun would mean that you see

> I am

and expect what follows to be a complement ([ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/subject-complement-grammar-1692001)) that is or describes the subject, I:

> I am TaliesinMerlin.
>
> I am happy.
>
> I am a person.

However, when the part following *I am* appears to be a verb, it is much more likely functioning as a verb phrase. In [this breakdown of conjugations](https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/have) for *have*, "I am having" is a first person present continuous form. So that should be read together as a verb in continuous aspect. As a result, in

> I am having difficulty with the test.

**am having** is the main verb phrase, and **difficulty** is a noun that heads the direct object *difficulty with the test*. The prepositional phrase *with the test* describes what the speaker is having difficulty with.

Comment: Actually, the matrix VP in full is "am having difficulty with the test", in which "am" is the predicator and "having difficulty with the test" is a subordinate clause functioning as complement of "am".  The direct object is the NP "difficulty with the test".

Comment: @BillJ I don't use CGEL, so for me the verb phrase is "am having" and the object is "difficulty," with "with the test" modifying the object. Perhaps you should write an answer reflecting your understanding of grammar. I think multiple perceptions of grammar are productive, but I'm not going to modify my answer to account for them all.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin By definition if "with the test" is modifying "difficulty" it is part of the same phrase. Therefore, if "difficulty" is part of the object so is "with the test"!

Comment: @Araucaria Exactly right. :)

Comment: That's what @BillJ said. Maybe you're talking at cross purposes?

Comment: And then in your analysis, "difficulty" isn't the object." The object's the whole noun phrase "difficulty with the test". No?

Comment: @Araucaria I thought that was clear (something modifying the direct object is a part of the direct object), but I acknowledge that I should be more explicit about that.

Comment: Something can't modify the object! It's either part of the object or it isn't :)

Comment: @Araucaria Do you have an issue with how I phrased it in the answer, or are you being pedantic? :)

Comment: Your new phrasing does the job. I hadn't seen that you'd modified it 10 mins ago. :)